# angular / ngrx store 4: Uninitialize state in component test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx-store-4.0

I have to implement ngrx/store (Version 4.0.3) in an existing angular (Version 4.3.3) application.

I have problems to test a component because of this error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.search.results')
```

After reading this document [Providing Store for testing](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/testing.md) I thought the implementation should be easy.

In my spec file I imported the StoreModule in the beforeEach method:

```
StoreModule.forRoot ({reducers}),
...
store = TestBed.get (Store);
spyOn (store, 'dispatch').and.callThrough ();
```

The reducer looks like:

```
import * as fromSearch from './search/search-reducer';
export interface State {
  search: fromSearch.State;
}

export const reducers = {
  search: fromSearch.reducer
};
```

and here the search-reducer:

```
export interface State {
  searchTerms: string;
  results: [];
  limit: SearchLimit;
}
// Imported: initialState & initalSearchLimitState
const initialState: State = {
  searchTerms: '',
  results:     [initialState],
  limit:       initalSearchLimitState
};

export function reducer (state = initialState, action: SearchActions.All): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SearchActions.SEARCH: {
      return {
        ...state,
        searchTerm: action.payload
      };
    }

    case SearchActions.SEARCH_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        results: action.payload
      };
    }

    case SearchActions.SEARCH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED: {
      return {
        ...state,
        limit: action.payload
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

In a method of the component I dispatch the specific action in a subscribe of a search service method (HTTP request):

```
this._searchService.search (query).subscribe (results => {
    this._store.dispatch (new SearchActions.SearchSuccess (results.data));
});
```

In the spec file, the search service is a mock service.

After reading a lot of answers on this site I tried to dispatch the specific action in the beforeEach method to initialize the `state.search.results` state. But I got the same error message.

How do I solve this state problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

I changed reducer from

```
export const reducers
```

to

```
export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State>
```

Furthermore, I have added the initial state in the import array of the beforeEach method.

Comment: Can you explain more or do you have code for setting the initial state in your spec file?

Comment: Sorry, I finished this project last year, and I do not own the source code. If you have problems with testing and initial state, you could look into this link: https://toddmotto.com/ngrx-store-testing-reducers. It's a simple explanation how to test.